# C#とPHP間で暗号化文字列をやりとりする方法

Tags: php, c#

お世話になります。
C#とPHPの間で暗号化した文字列をやりとりする必要があるのですが、PHP側でどのようにすればよいかよくわからずにいます。
とりあえず、C#とPHPのコードを記載しますので、何かアドバイスをいただけますと幸いです。

### C#のコード

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;

public class App{
public static void Main(){
var test = new test_crypt.test();
string result = test.Encrypt("abc", "test");
MessageBox.Show(result);
string dresult = test.Decrypt(result, "test");
MessageBox.Show(dresult);
}
}

namespace test_crypt{
public class test{
private Encoding _encode = Encoding.UTF8;
private byte[] _salt = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes("1234567890");

public string Encrypt(string text, string password){
byte[] bytes = _encode.GetBytes(text);
byte[] inArray = Encrypt(bytes, password);
return Convert.ToBase64String(inArray);
}

private byte[] Encrypt(byte[] strBytes, string password){
SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = GetAlgorithm();
byte[] key, iv;
GenerateKeyFromPassword(password, algorithm.KeySize, out key, algorithm.BlockSize, out iv);
algorithm.Key = key;
algorithm.IV = iv;
ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = algorithm.CreateEncryptor();
byte[] result = cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);
cryptoTransform.Dispose();
return result;
}

public string Decrypt(string text, string password){
byte[] strBytes = Convert.FromBase64String(text);
byte[] bytes = Decrypt(strBytes, password);
return _encode.GetString(bytes);
}

private byte[] Decrypt(byte[] strBytes, string password){
SymmetricAlgorithm algorithm = GetAlgorithm();
byte[] key, iv;
GenerateKeyFromPassword(password, algorithm.KeySize, out key, algorithm.BlockSize, out iv);
algorithm.Key = key;
algorithm.IV = iv;
ICryptoTransform cryptoTransform = null;
try{
cryptoTransform = algorithm.CreateDecryptor();
return cryptoTransform.TransformFinalBlock(strBytes, 0, strBytes.Length);
}
catch (CryptographicException ex){
throw new Exception("復号化に失敗しました。\n" + ex.Message);
}
finally{
cryptoTransform.Dispose();
}
}

protected void GenerateKeyFromPassword(string password, int keySize, out byte[] key, int blockSize, out byte[] iv){
Rfc2898DeriveBytes rfc2898DeriveBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(password, _salt);
rfc2898DeriveBytes.IterationCount = 1;
key = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(keySize / 8);
iv = rfc2898DeriveBytes.GetBytes(blockSize / 8);
}

protected virtual SymmetricAlgorithm GetAlgorithm(){
return new AesManaged();
}
}
}
```

### PHPのコード

```
<?php
$method = 'AES-128-CBC';
$password = 'test';
$plain_text = 'abc';
$salt = '1234567890';

$key_iv = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, 32+16, 1);
$key = substr($key_iv, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($key_iv, 32, 16);
$encrypted_text = openssl_encrypt($plain_text, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
$decrypted_text = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_text, $method, $key, 0, $iv);
echo $encrypted_text."<br>";
echo $decrypted_text."<br>";
?>
```

---

以上、よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PHPでは[`openssl_pbkdf2`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.openssl-pbkdf2.php)か[`hash_pbkdf2`](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)で.NETの[`Rfc2898DeriveBytes`](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8)と同等の結果が得られます。

```
<?php
$password = 'test';
$plain_text = 'abc';
$salt = "1234567890";

$keyiv = openssl_pbkdf2($password, $salt, 32+16, 1);
//$keyiv = hash_pbkdf2("sha1", $password, $salt, 1, 32+16, TRUE);
$key = substr($keyiv, 0, 32);
$iv = substr($keyiv, 32, 16);

$encrypted_text = openssl_encrypt($plain_text, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
$decrypted_text = openssl_decrypt($encrypted_text, 'AES-256-CBC', $key, 0, $iv);
echo $encrypted_text;
echo $decrypted_text;
?>
```

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。アドバイスいただいたコードでPHPを書き直してみたところ、とりあえず、暗号化には成功しましたが、C#で復号化すると、例外メッセージとして、「パディングは無効なので、削除できません。」というエラーが返ってきてしまうようです。

Comment: @user29034 確認ですが、質問のコードで暗号化結果はC# / PHP共に`rFs9iKTw8xuIsFUIcYdrlA==`となりますが一致していますか？

Comment: すみません。ちゃんとみてみたら、手元にあったC#のソースコードが違いました。PHPコード側を修正したところ、C#でもうまく複合することができました。お手数をおかけして、申し訳ありませんでした。ありがとうございました。

Answer (score 3):

C#のコードは[RFC2898](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2898)に記載されているPBKDF2(PKCS #5 v2.0)に基づきkeyとivを作成し、AES-256-CBCで暗号化/復号化しているようです。PHP側でもPBKDF2に基づきkeyとivを作成すれば、同様に暗号化/復号化が可能になるはずです。PBKDF2用の関数[hash_pbkdf2](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.hash-pbkdf2.php)が用意されていますので、こちらの関数を使用することで、同様のkeyとivを作成することができます。使用方法等はリンク先のPHPマニュアル等を確認してください。

異なるコード間でやり取りする場合の注意事項としては、同じPBKDF2に基づいていても、暗号アルゴリズム、ハッシュアルゴリズム、反復回数が同じでなければなりません。C#側の[AesManaged](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.aesmanaged?view=netframework-4.8)はASEですが、鍵長を128,192,256で選択でき、指定しなかった場合にどれになるかはわかりませんでした。サイズを固定するか、あらかじめ確認しておいてください。C#側の[Rfc2898DeriveBytes](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rfc2898derivebytes?view=netframework-4.8)が使用するハッシュアルゴリズムはHMAC SHA1固定のようですが、PHP側の`hash_pbkdf2`は複数選択できることに注意してください。なお、現在のコードでは、`rfc2898DeriveBytes.IterationCount = 1;`から反復回数はたった1回です。

現在のコードにはセキュリティ上よろしくない点が二つあります(何故ダメなのかの理由は長くなるので、省略します)。これらを解決しておくことを推奨します。

1. saltが固定である。
   saltを固定化してはいけません。saltは暗号論的に安全な乱数生成機(ハードウェアエントロピーによる乱数や暗号論的擬似乱数生成機等)を使用して生成してください。暗号論的に安全な乱数生成機とは、C#であれば[RNGCryptoServiceProvider](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.security.cryptography.rngcryptoserviceprovider?view=netframework-4.8)、PHPであれば[random_byets](https://www.php.net/manual/ja/function.random-bytes.php)等です。
   暗号データを保存する際は、saltと暗号化されたデータをセットで保存しておくようにします。秘密にしておく必要があるのは、パスワードのみです。
2. 反復回数が1回である。
   PBKDF2が書かれたRFC2898では反復回数を指定していませんが、1000回以上を推奨しています。1000回以上に増やしてください。なお、C#のRfc2898DeriveBytesのデフォルトは1000回です。

Comment: アドバイスありがとうございます。とりあえず、いただいたアドバイスを元にコードを修正してみましたが、PHP側で生成した文字列がC#側では複合できないようです。ちなみに、C#側でkeySizeを確認してみたところ、256のようでした。それから、セキュリティ上の問題点についてのご指摘もありがとうございました。